# Wait for activity to finish in non-activity class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a method in my application which starts a new Activity which starts the Camera Application. The Camera Application returns a result (picture taken or not taken), and I store this result in the Intent-Bundle.

In the original method I want to read this bundle, which does not work because the activity is not finished yet.

How can I wait for the activity to finish before going on in my method?

**Method**

```
@Override    
public boolean startChallenge(Context context) {
        Intent cam = new Intent(context, CameraIntent.class);
        cam.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(cam);

        Boolean done = cam.getExtras().get("done"); // << this fails obviously
}
```

**Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE);
 }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    intent = getIntent();
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            intent.putExtra("done", true);  
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            intent.putExtra("done", false);     
        }
    }
    finish();
}
```

I would like to keep the structure of the code because the startChallenge() Method is inherited from a superclass (Challenge) and startChallenge is different from type to type (e.g. there is a challenge where you have to take a picture, another challenge where you have to answer something, and so on). The method gets called in another activity, depending on the type of challenge.

Comment: Not sure I got it, but couldn't you start your activity with startActivityForResult() also?

Comment: You cannot "wait". You should provide some kind of a callback method that is called when the "challenge" is completed. The callback method can then continue the process (whatever that is). In this way you decouple the "initiation" of the challenge and the "completion" of the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

*startChallenge* should have a reference to the Activity that expects the result back to be able to call startActivityForResult

**Method**

```
@Override    
public boolean startChallenge(Activity activityB) {// Activity B in which you are expecting this result back.
    Intent cam = new Intent(activityB, ActivityA.class);
    activityB.startActivityForResult(cam, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_CAMERA);
}
```

**Activity A**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    intent = getIntent();
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            intent.putExtra("done", true);  
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            intent.putExtra("done", false);     
        }
    }

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Another approach would be to use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto)

**Activity A**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ImageCapturedEvent(true));
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ImageCapturedEvent(false));
        }
    }

    finish();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your approach but I have a question: 
- where is REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_CAMERA referenced? Or why is it necessary? 
At which point can I access the intent.getExtra()?

Comment: It can be any int value to check against requestCode in ActivityB